# Do children documents have to be indexed after their parents in Elasticsearch?

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, parent-child, batch-processing

Say I would like to index all documents from an external store, do I have to make sure all parent document indexing requests have been send (or even fully processed!) before I start indexing children documents?

Answer (score 2):

For sure the parent document has to exist. Otherwise elastic search can't create the relation between the two documents.

But you do not have to index ALL the parent document before indexing the children. For instance in a personnal project, when i want to index a child document, i amfirst checking if the future parent exist, if not i am creating it with empty fields but the good ID and then creating the corresponding child document.

What matter here is that the `_parent` field in the child document find the id referencing the parent document.

Answer (score 0):

> The parent document doesn’t need to exist at  time of indexing.

http://2013.berlinbuzzwords.de/sites/2013.berlinbuzzwords.de/files/slides/document-relations-bbuz-2013.pdf slide 14

Comment: Please do not accuse others of down voting you; you have no idea who did so or why.

Comment: We have two conflicting opinions, have anyone validated one from this answer? I will do so shortly, but no point in doubling somebodies work.